# android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout could not be instantiated - Implementation's broken class path

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm creating a navigation drawer and my project cannot instantiate the DrawerLayout class. How do I fix it?

I'm creating an app and I want to have a navigation coming from the side of the screen.
When I tried to enter the DrawerLayout I've came across rendering problems and missing styles.
My theme is 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.NoActionBar'.
None of the answers posted online helped me...
I've searched in the posts below:
[Rendering problems, could not find android.support.v4.widget.Drawerlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882191/rendering-problems-could-not-find-android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout)  &
[java android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not being found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783007/java-android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout-not-being-found)  &
[Rendering Problems: Class could not be instantiated: - android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830927/rendering-problems-class-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v4-widget)  &
[Android: Navigation Drawer activity - "The following classes could not be instantiated:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251365/android-navigation-drawer-activity-the-following-classes-could-not-be-instan)  &
[android.support.v4.widget.Drawerlayout could not be instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446546/android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout-could-not-be-instantiated)  &
[android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout Cannot be instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875910/android-support-v4-widget-drawerlayout-cannot-be-instantiated)

When I've looked inside project structure I've found 30 problems that I think are whats causing this.

```
The '30 Problems':
1. Library Gradle: android.arch.core:runtime-1.1.1 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\1ed9abb76df57a728e56a0d377980a42\res [Fix]
2. Library Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-1.1.1 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-1.1.1.aar\bb114928e69dc70ac669dbbb75092cb3\res [Fix]
3. Library Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core-1.1.1 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.1.aar\8ff3e0bbe6d32a4fe667e4f0b7dbcdc6\res [Fix]
4. Library Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime-1.1.1 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\77ed501e72ab2e9c8657211a431aef75\res [Fix]
5. Library Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel-1.1.1 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.1.aar\de829b9d223f4f8f74006d0d62f94188\res [Fix]
6. Library Gradle: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core-3.0.2 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-core-3.0.2.aar\f18942ca7086b3fed7fbe1ab6bdf2f82\res [Fix]
7. Library Gradle: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2.aar\28e9ae2f90ceee2efcdc553851d9c2ec\res [Fix]
8. Library Gradle: com.android.support.test:monitor-1.0.2 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\monitor-1.0.2.aar\42df670f042897b728f01ee50faa0bbe\res [Fix]
9. Library Gradle: com.android.support.test:runner-1.0.2 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runner-1.0.2.aar\bf542da1f75fcb465f7a87191d034c57\res [Fix]
10. Library Gradle: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\682838ee28152ff81a88adc290532743\res [Fix]
11. Library Gradle: com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0.aar\daf27663d33e8ad47792184a939b46de\res [Fix]
12. Library Gradle: com.android.support:cursoradapter-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\cursoradapter-28.0.0.aar\4cc8400b5bc0090a45f9b5aa86913a67\res [Fix]
13. Library Gradle: com.android.support:customview-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\customview-28.0.0.aar\c1b96ade1c1f810680f95fed2dd38150\res [Fix]
14. Library Gradle: com.android.support:documentfile-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\documentfile-28.0.0.aar\101102579587b4c97690c3906a9fbc45\res [Fix]
15. Library Gradle: com.android.support:drawerlayout-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\drawerlayout-28.0.0.aar\887e59c896b92e48cd63d660a3ad0d2b\res [Fix]
16. Library Gradle: com.android.support:interpolator-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\interpolator-28.0.0.aar\3d7173e69a76d2ab6de6f99ed609f170\res [Fix]
17. Library Gradle: com.android.support:loader-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\loader-28.0.0.aar\011b279f73f14d976da4fefa2c049945\res [Fix]
18. Library Gradle: com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0.aar\274feffa4a7039599e2c8d2beda26909\res [Fix]
19. Library Gradle: com.android.support:print-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\print-28.0.0.aar\b39a51f640b52355ef1e0b5faf7ffd8e\res [Fix]
20. Library Gradle: com.android.support:slidingpanelayout-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\slidingpanelayout-28.0.0.aar\9bd00f1e7dd4a51a03b2b92185c7e486\res [Fix]
21. Library Gradle: com.android.support:support-core-ui-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-28.0.0.aar\e6a91ff213a21cd983a7fb6bd4c2e053\res [Fix]
22. Library Gradle: com.android.support:support-core-utils-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-28.0.0.aar\ee00eb82fa1334c7d0b8318162ec09b7\res [Fix]
23. Library Gradle: com.android.support:support-fragment-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-28.0.0.aar\554530d0b22d35d050ce20c30641a9c9\res [Fix]
24. Library Gradle: com.android.support:support-v4-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-v4-28.0.0.aar\c4e4a038d28d012e80847b5e3950e75f\res [Fix]
25. Library Gradle: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\9586bcb98270a789084fec5886c2b31b\res [Fix]
26. Library Gradle: com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar\f606599c716f9a4c2ac21f4fbd220878\res [Fix]
27. Library Gradle: com.android.support:versionedparcelable-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar\2cb1929b825c084558dea2e1f7325933\res [Fix]
28. Library Gradle: com.android.support:viewpager-28.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewpager-28.0.0.aar\eccad61e3466954426c6e599ee6846a4\res [Fix]
29. Library Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport-16.0.0 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-places-placereport-16.0.0.aar\18c1ae959910956c0d3900a36cdf21c9\res [Fix]
30. Library Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-16.0.1 has broken classes path:   C:\Users\ys571\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-tasks-16.0.1.aar\3bab695efab919e8714ee099972c1110\res [Fix]
```

The exception I received from the DrawerLayout is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:336)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>(DrawerLayout.java:310)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor3668.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I expect the implemented dependencies to not have a broken classes path that I believe caused the exceptions.

Comment: are you using `androidx`?

Comment: @KaranMer I don't think so... I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: have you tried to use invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: no, How do I do that? and how can it help?

Comment: it is there in File menu

Comment: @KaranMer Ok so after trying to invalidate cache and restart it still didn't change

Comment: After downloading Android Studio and installing sdk again it was fixed. I thinks the problem is the intellij download of the android sdk